# Assalamualaikkum, if someone gives me to eat an improper cost meal, is it Haram to eat without realise it?

Tags: halal-haram, islamic-basis

The way a person purchased the food was improper cost in Islamic , He gave to me eat and I've eaten without knowing it's improper cost way but after that I understood it's sin (haram) so this what is the remedy? 
Can I Sadaqa that food money to poor people to relief this sin?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "improper cost"?

Answer (score 1):

If you have eaten such food and at that time you didn't know the cost of food was halal or haram than you haven't committed any sin because you are unaware of that thing.